# How to pass variables to overridden toString() method?

Tags: c#, overriding, tostring

Is it possible to pass in a `bool` variable into an overridden `toString()` method, so it can conditionally print the object in different formats?

Comment: You may want to look into [`IFormattable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformattable.aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define *overload* method of `ToString()`.

```
public string ToString(bool status){
  //
}
```

Comment: in the actual print statement how yould you pass the bool to it. Say i wanted to do Console.WriteLine(object). Where do you pass the bool?

Comment: @user1498918: By explicitly calling the method.

Answer (score 2):

The typical pattern for parametrized ToString() is to declare an overload with a string parameter.

Example:

```
class Foo
{
    public string ToString(string format)
    {
        //change behavior based on format
    }
}
```

For a framework example see Guid.ToString

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about your own class, you could do the following:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public bool Flag { get; set; }

    public MyClass()
    {
        Flag = false;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (Flag)
        {
            return "Ok";
        }
        else
        {
            return "Bad";
        }
    }
}
```

And use it

```
MyClass c = new MyClass();
Console.WriteLine(c); //Bad
c.Flag = true;
Console.WriteLine(c); //Ok
Console.ReadLine();
```

Your `Flag` could be some private field and change its value, depending on some inner conditions. It's all up to you.

Answer (score 0):

No. An overriding method must have the same signature as the method it's overriding. This means that it can't have any more parameters, since that would change the signature. I would just make a new method for the other format you want.